# XSD error: XML element is not expected

Tags: xml, xsd

Read the other questions here, but can't figure out why is the following XML not valid against http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/data.xsd

How on earth should I add multiple elements into the XML. The schemaValidate() response:

> DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Element
>   '{http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/stock.xsd}stockHeader':
>   This element is not expected. Expected is one of (
>   {http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/stock.xsd}stockDetail,
>   {http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/stock.xsd}stockAttach,
>   {http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/stock.xsd}stockSerialNumber,
>   {http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/stock.xsd}stockPriceItem,
>   {http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/stock.xsd}print).

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
<dat:dataPack xmlns:dat="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/data.xsd"
xmlns:stk="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/stock.xsd"
xmlns:typ="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/type.xsd"
id="Sklad" ico="02021123"
application="Eshop" version="2.0" note="Import zasob.">
    <dat:dataPackItem id="ZAS20160809" version="2.0">
        <stk:stock version="2.0">

                <stk:stockHeader>
                    <stk:stockType>card</stk:stockType>
                    <stk:code>C Set-G/Fe-K</stk:code>
                </stk:stockHeader>
                <stk:stockHeader>
                    <stk:stockType>card</stk:stockType>
                    <stk:code>C Set-G/Zn-K</stk:code>
                </stk:stockHeader>
        </stk:stock>
    </dat:dataPackItem>
</dat:dataPack>
```

Your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to add multiple stock updates. As Ghislain Fourny mentioned,

> `<stk:stockHeader>`

can occure only one.

For multiple stock updates use

> `<dat:dataPackItem >`

For example:

```
<dat:dataPackItem id="ZAS001" version="2.0">
  <stk:stock version="2.0">
    <stk:actionType>
      <stk:add/>
    </stk:actionType>
    <stk:stockHeader>
    ...
    ...
    </stk:stockHeader>    
  </stk:stock>
</dat:dataPackItem>
<dat:dataPackItem id="ZAS002" version="2.0">
  <stk:stock version="2.0">
    <stk:actionType>
      <stk:add/>
    </stk:actionType>
    <stk:stockHeader>
    ...
    ...
    </stk:stockHeader>    
  </stk:stock>
</dat:dataPackItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

**stockHeader** is declared in stock.xsd like so:

```
<xsd:element
  name="stockHeader"
  type="stk:stockHeaderType"
  minOccurs="0"/>
```

The absence of maxOccurs defaults to a value of 1, so that there can be either 0 or 1 occurrence of stockHeader.

To allow more, it should be changed to

```
<xsd:element
  name="stockHeader"
  type="stk:stockHeaderType"
  minOccurs="0"
  maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```